# concurrency in prolog

Tags: prolog

block of code is like below..

```
1.fork(sort_zero([H1|T1],[H2|T2],HY,0)),
2.fork(sort_zero([H1|T1],[H3|T3],HZ,0)),
3.
4.set_zero(HY,HZ,HZ2,1),
```

In above code I am getting manipulated list HY and HZ and than I further working with that lists HY and HZ, what should I write in line no. 3 to insure that line 4 will be executed after complete execution of both fork calls.
 I want a satement which works as barrier in line no.3.
both fork calls are mutually independent. I have also tried by copying [H1|T1] list in another variable and passed it in line 2 instead of [H1|T1].

Comment: in your Prolog manual near to fork/1 there will be something about lock, or mutex....

Answer (score 0):

In SWI-Prolog, you could use threads and synchronize them with join:

```
thread_create( (sort_zero([H1|T1],[H2|T2],HY,0), thread_exit(HY)), IdY, []),
thread_create( (sort_zero([H1|T1],[H3|T3],HZ,0), thread_exit(HZ)), IdZ, []),
thread_join(IdY, exited(HY)),
thread_join(IdZ, exited(HZ)),
set_zero(HY,HZ,HZ2,1),
...
```